# How can I do one-operand math with my Java calculator?

Tags: java, math, if-statement, operators, calculator

I have been trying to create a simple calculator in Java for a while now, and I have successfully been able to make the program work with two-operand equations (+, -, *, /, and ^). However, I was wondering how I would be able to do one-operand math problems - absolute value(using the symbol "|"), square root (using the symbol 'v'), rounding to the closest integer (using the symbol '~'), sin (s), cos (c), and tangent (t).

I have attempted the absolute value operand which can be seen in:

```
if (operator == '|') {
            answer = Math.abs(numA);
}
// In the main class
```

and:

```
double absolute(double a) {
            double answer = Math.abs(a);
            return answer;
}
// In the maths class
```

This code only works if you enter in values for example like this: `-3 | -3` (Note: I have noticed that it is only the first number that the absolute value operation is performed upon. The second number can be whatever you want (if you entered `-3 | -4` your answer would still be `3`) as long as it is, indeed, a number.

Any help for solving this problem and help figuring out the other single-operand operations would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

The source code for my program is below:

```
package calculator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello, welcome to my calculator");
    System.out.println("Enter in some stuff you want to me to calculate");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("If you need help please type \"help\"");
    System.out.println("If at anytime you want to leave, type \"quit\"");
    System.out.println("Hit enter to continue.");

    String s1 = scan.nextLine();

    if (s1.equals("help")){
        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("Double operand commands:");
        System.out.println("Addition: '+' (Ex: 'a + b' )");
        System.out.println("Subtraction: '-' (Ex: 'a - b' )");
        System.out.println("Multiplication: '*' (Ex: 'a * b' ) ");
        System.out.println("Division: '/' (Ex: 'a / b' )");
        System.out.println("Exponents: '^' (Ex: 'a ^ b' )");

        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Maths maths = new Maths();

    double answer = 0;
    double numA, numB;
    char operator;
    boolean quit = false;


    while (true) {

    System.out.print("Please enter your equation: ");

    String s=input.next();

    if(s.equals("quit")){
        System.out.println("Thank you for using my program!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    numA = Double.parseDouble(s);
    operator = input.next().charAt(0);
    numB = input.nextDouble();        

    if (operator == '+') {
        answer = maths.add(numA, numB);
    }

    if (operator == '-') {
        answer = maths.subtract(numA, numB);
    }

    if (operator == '*') {
        answer = maths.multiply(numA, numB);
    }

    if (operator == '/') {
        answer = maths.divide(numA, numB);
    }

    if (operator == '^') {
        answer = maths.power(numA, numB);
    }

    if (operator == '|') {
        answer = Math.abs(numA);
    }

        System.out.println(answer);        



        }

    }

}

class Maths {

    double add(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a+b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double subtract(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a-b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double multiply(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a*b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double divide(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a/b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double power(double a, double b){
        double answer =a;

        for (int x=2; x<=b; x++){
            answer *= a;
        }

        return answer;
    }

    double absolute(double a) {
        double answer = Math.abs(a);
        return answer;
    }


}
```

Comment: don't do `numB = input.nextDouble()` unless the operator requires it.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks! How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Not terribly elegant, but you could move that line into each of the `if(operator ==` blocks that need it.

Comment: That works...but like you said not very elegant, and I kind of wanted the operand to be placed before the said number rather than after

Comment: In this case, you're probably best off reading the whole line as a String, and parsing that as appropriate. (look at the first word to see if it is an operator that can go there etc)

Comment: @Thilo Sorry, I'm a high school student just getting started with programming...how would you do this? Could you show me somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some modification in your existing code so that it can suit in all cases and allow future extension of functions. You can understand the changes through comments. Also, the code will be able to run, if user provide only one input for functions, where only single parameter is enough. I did not change any of your functions.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello, welcome to my calculator");
        System.out.println("Enter in some stuff you want to me to calculate");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("If you need help please type \"help\"");
        System.out.println("If at anytime you want to leave, type \"quit\"");
        System.out.println("Hit enter to continue.");

        String s1 = scan.nextLine();

        if (s1.equals("help")) {
            System.out.println(" ");

            System.out.println("Double operand commands:");
            System.out.println("Addition: '+' (Ex: 'a + b' )");
            System.out.println("Subtraction: '-' (Ex: 'a - b' )");
            System.out.println("Multiplication: '*' (Ex: 'a * b' ) ");
            System.out.println("Division: '/' (Ex: 'a / b' )");
            System.out.println("Exponents: '^' (Ex: 'a ^ b' )");

            System.out.println(" ");
        } else if (s1.equals("quit")) {
            System.out.println("Thank you for using my program!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        Maths maths = new Maths();

        double answer = 0;
        double numA=0.0, numB=0.0;
        char operator;
        boolean quit = false;

        while (true) {

            System.out.print("Please enter your equation: ");

            //First scan the function as a string
            String s = input.next();

            if (s.equals("quit")) {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using my program!");
                System.exit(0);
            }

          //We will use regex to find the operator, so we will omit all alphabetic letter or numeric number or decimal
            String operator1 = s.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9.]",""); 
          //For functions like -4|, the operator1 will be -| after replacing through regex, we will only take the second digit as operator to prevent error
            if(operator1.length()==1) 
            operator = operator1.charAt(0);
            else
                operator = operator1.charAt(1); 
            String[] num11 = (s.split("[^0-9,.]"));
        //String array num11 may contain null string after splitting using regex, we will remove those null string and store only variable values in an arraylist
           ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < num11.length; i++)
            {
                if (!num11[i].equals(""))
                {
                    arraylist.add(num11[i]);
                }
            }



            if(arraylist.size()==1){
            numA = Double.parseDouble(arraylist.get(0));    
            numB=numA;}
            else if(arraylist.size()==2){
            numA = Double.parseDouble(arraylist.get(0));    
            numB = Double.parseDouble(arraylist.get(1));

            }




            if (operator == '+') {
                answer = maths.add(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '-') {
                answer = maths.subtract(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '*') {
                answer = maths.multiply(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '/') {
                answer = maths.divide(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '^') {
                answer = maths.power(numA, numB);
            }

            if (operator == '|') {
                answer = Math.abs(numA);
            }

            System.out.println(answer);

        }

    }

    public static class Maths {

        public void Maths(){};

        double add(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a + b;
            return answer;
        }

        double subtract(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a - b;
            return answer;
        }

        double multiply(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a * b;
            return answer;
        }

        double divide(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a / b;
            return answer;
        }

        double power(double a, double b) {
            double answer = a;

            for (int x = 2; x <= b; x++) {
                answer *= a;
            }

            return answer;
        }

        double absolute(double a) {
            double answer = Math.abs(a);
            return answer;
        }

    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Please enter your equation: +4+4
8.0
Please enter your equation: 4+4
8.0
Please enter your equation: 4+3
7.0
Please enter your equation: 4-3
1.0
Please enter your equation: 4/3
1.3333333333333333
Please enter your equation: -4|
4.0
Please enter your equation: 4|
4.0
Please enter your equation: 3^2
9.0
```

Comment: Thanks Tarek...just out of curiosity, is there a way to do the same thing...except without using Rebecca

Comment: What you mean by Rebecca? Regex? If you mean Regex, then yes, there is way. But Regex is most preferable and its easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to check whether first number is actually a number. Then do what you want to do accordingly. Additionally, you can handle erroneous user inputs using regular exceptions. So you won't have `java.lang.NumberFormatException`s if you enter "3+3"

```
if (s.matches("^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$")) { //Check whether first number is actually a number
    numA = Double.parseDouble(s);
    operator = input.next().charAt(0);
    numB = input.nextDouble();

} else {
    operator = s.charAt(0);
    numA = input.nextDouble();
    numB = 0;
}
```